# create logical values in R

Tags: r, boolean

```
this is my head(both):

     gender  prog     start          grade    omreg
1     man     FRIST    2012-09-21     <NA>    FALSE
2     man     FRIST      <NA>        <NA>     FALSE
3    woman      FRIST    <NA>         <NA>     FALSE
4    woman      FRIST   2012-01-11    <NA>    FALSE
5    woman      NMFIK     <NA>        <NA>    FALSE
6     man     FRIST    2014-06-12       A     FALSE
7    woman    FRIST      2014-06-12     B     FALSE               
8    woman    FRIST      2014-06-12     A     FALSE
9    woman    FRIST      2014-06-12     A     FALSE
10   woman    FRIST      2014-06-12     E     FALSE
```

What I need help with: To make the column values in the 'grade' column as logical.
The ratings in the material is grade A-E. If you have not received a passing grade it says .

It is not interesting to me what grade you got, but only if you failed or passed.

As logical values i would like to have:

```
TRUE= grades from A-E (if you passed). I would like ti call TRUE for "yes"
FALSE = <NA> (if you failed) and i want to call it "no"
```

I have tested as.logical(), how should I do to get the code right?

Answer (score 2):

You can simply use `is.na()` to check whether `grade` is `NA`.

```
within(both, passed <- !is.na(grade))
```

This adds a column to the data frame that's `TRUE` when `grade` is not missing and `FALSE` otherwise.

Thanks to Richard Scriven for the useful stylistic tip!

Comment: `with()` or `$`, commit to one :) Or `within(both, passed <- !is.na(grade))`

Comment: @RichardScriven: Thanks for your input, I appreciate it. Updated to use your tip. For some reason I always forget about `within()`.